# I tried to export the Active Directory field "Secretary" to a CSV file. The output does not contain the expected information

Tags: powershell, active-directory, export-csv

Why does this not work?

```
get-ADuser -filter * -property * 
    | select-object samaccountname, manager, secretary 
    | export-csv -path c:\temp\output.csv
```

The secretary field all returned

> Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection

But this works:

```
get-ADuser -filter * -property * 
    | select-object samaccountname, manager, secretary 
    | out-file -filepath c:\temp\output.txt
```

For some reason Active Directory stores the Secretary field inside a pair of "{}" but the manager field is not enclosed in "{}". The "{}" messed up the export-csv. Is there a way to work around that?

The secretary field in Active Directory cannot be exported in CSV format. Why? All the values in the Secretary field is output as `Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection` instead of something like `CN=Joe Smith,OU=Users,DC=ACME,DC=com`.

Is it because of the Secretary field is internally stored with "{}"? Is there a way to strip that off?

Comment: That simply means that custom attribute `secretary` is defined as multi-valued (an array). You can join the values with some character like the semi-colon `;` and Export-Csv should be fine. Do not use `-Properties *` as this is a waste of resources. Only specify the properties you actually need

Comment: Except that Export-CSV for secretary field just doesn't work, regardless of how many entries are in there. You can try it yourself.

Comment: I can't try because my ad schema doesn't have such attribute. Like I said, join the values as in `@{Name = 'secretaries'; Expression= {$_.Secretary -join ';'}}`